# Role of 'that' in this sentence?

Tags: parsing

I am recently reading an English book to improve my English skills.

In the book I am now reading, there is a sentence,

> There is nothing Hypnos and Morepheus can do to soothe your aching body, to calm your racing mind, to ease your wounded spirit, **that** I cannot match with something sweet and warm of my own.

I cannot figure out what the role of bolded "that" in this sentence is. I believe it is a conjunction but don't know what the exact function it is doing in this sentence.

Comment: "There is nothing [they] can do.... that I cannot match..." (Hypnos and Morpheus are classical gods of sleep.)

Comment: I'd say it's just a ***relativiser***. In principle, it's no different to *There is nothing [**that**] I cannot do* (in that syntactically speaking it's ***optional***). But because of the specific context here - so much text between the relativiser and the antecedent noun ("nothing", here) that it refers back to - it would be stylistically / idiomatically appalling to omit ***that*** in OPs example, even though it's fine to do that with my shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

> *There is nothing Hypnos and Morepheus can do to soothe your aching*
> *body, to calm your racing mind, to ease your wounded spirit, that I*
> *cannot match with something sweet and warm of my own.*

Yes, it's a conjunction, more specifically a 'subordinator'. Its function is that of 'marker', i.e. it marks the clause *that I cannot match with something sweet and warm of my own* as being subordinate.

This is called a 'stacked' relative construction, one where a defining relative clause combines with its antecedent to form a larger unit which is antecedent for a second defining relative clause.

In this case, *Hypnos and Morepheus can do to soothe your aching body, to calm your* *racing mind, to ease your wounded spirit* combines with its antecedent "nothing" to give *nothing Hypnos and Morepheus can do to soothe your aching body, to calm your racing mind, to ease your wounded spirit* and this is then the antecedent for the second relative clause *that I cannot match with something sweet and warm of my own*.

This kind of recursion is known as 'stacking'.